# Data isn't updating in Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My first time asking questions here I think I'm going insane. Working on a school project, I am creating an app like Goodreads, I have recyclerView which lists all the books from database(reading data works fine) and a different fragment where you can write a review for each book. So I have 3 layouts(main_activity layout,review layout and a layout that designs an item for recyclerView).

The problem is when I click save button which is supposed to save a review ni database it does nothing. I have a collection called "books" which has 8 documents and fields such as title,author,rating,image,review. All fields are string types. My rules allow writing and reading data. I have no idea what to do if anyone has better insight I will be really thankful

Main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),BookRecyclerAdapter.ContentListener {
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: BookRecyclerAdapter
    private val db = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layout.activity_main)
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(id.booksList)

        db.collection("books")
            .get() //da dohvati sve dokumente
            .addOnSuccessListener { //unutar ovoga pristup svim podadcima koji su se ucitali
                val items: ArrayList<Book> = ArrayList()
                for (data in it.documents) { //stvori novu data varijablu za svaki dohvaceni dokument(element?)
                    val book =
                        data.toObject(Book::class.java) //sve podatke pretvaramo u model preko toObject u Person
                    if (book != null) {
                        book.id = data.id  //postavljanje ida
                        items.add(book) //dodavanje gotovog eprsona u listu
                    }
                }
                recyclerAdapter = BookRecyclerAdapter(items, this@MainActivity)
                recyclerView.apply {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    adapter = recyclerAdapter
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("MainActivity", "Error getting documents", exception)
            }
    }



    override fun onItemButtonClick(index: Int, item: Book, clickType: ItemClickType) {

        if (clickType == ItemClickType.SAVE) {
            db.collection("books").document(item.id)
                .set(item)
                .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
                .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e) }


        }
        else if (clickType == ItemClickType.REVIEW) {
            val newFragment: Fragment = ReviewFragment()
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction? = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction?.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            transaction?.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction?.commit();

        }

    }
}
```

BookRecyclerAdapter

```
package hr.ferit.enasalaj.zavrsni

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide


enum class ItemClickType {
    SAVE,
    REVIEW
}

class BookRecyclerAdapter(
    val items:ArrayList<Book>,
    val listener: ContentListener,

): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val mainView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_books, parent, false)
        val reviewView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.review, parent, false)
        return BookViewHolder(mainView, reviewView)
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is BookViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(position, listener, items[position])
            }
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }


    class BookViewHolder(val view: View,val review: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val bookImage =
            view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        private val bookAuthor =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.bookAuthor)
        private val bookTitle =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.bookTitle)
        private val bookRating =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.bookRating)
        private val reviewButton =
            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.writeReviewButton)
        public val saveButton =
            review.findViewById<Button>(R.id.saveButton)
        public val bookReview =
            review.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.saveReview)


        fun bind(
            index: Int,
            listener: ContentListener,
            item: Book,
        ) {


            Glide.with(view.context).load(item.image).into(bookImage)
            bookAuthor.setText(item.author)
            bookTitle.setText(item.title)
            bookRating.setText(item.rating)
            bookReview.setText(item.review)


            reviewButton.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemButtonClick(index,item,ItemClickType.REVIEW)

            }

            saveButton.setOnClickListener{
                listener.onItemButtonClick(index,item,ItemClickType.SAVE)
            }


        }
    }

    interface ContentListener {
        fun onItemButtonClick(index: Int, item: Book, clickType: ItemClickType)
    }
}
```

And here is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'hr.ferit.enasalaj.zavrsni'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hr.ferit.enasalaj.zavrsni"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


}
```

Comment: Your code shows a couple of logs. Do you see any of those logs in the logcat?